# Streamlit: How to store value of variable in cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, streamlit

I am using 2 differnt radio options for performing different tasks. I want to capture image form one and then do some operation later in the option 2. When I try to change the radio option to 2 after storing a frame in `my_image` (in the option 1), there comes an error in thre streamlit `NameError: name 'my_image' is not defined`. I was thinking that it can be done by storing the variable `my_image` in cache but I don't know how to do this. Is there any other way to do this.

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2

def Camera():
    frames1 = st.empty()
    button1 = st.button('DONE', key=0)
    while cap.isOpened():
        frames1.image(cap.read()[1], channels="BGR")
        if button1:
            my_image = cap.read()[1]
            cap.release()
            break
    return my_image

option = st.sidebar.radio('Choose the option', [1, 2])

if option == 1:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    my_image = Camera()
    st.image(my_image, channels="BGR")

if option == 2:
    st.image(my_image, channels='BGR')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess I needed this [SessionState](https://gist.github.com/tvst/036da038ab3e999a64497f42de966a92) gist copied in a SessionState.py file. 
I initialize a variable `session_state = SessionState.get(name='', img=None)`.
In the `option==1`, assigned `session_state.img = my_image` and then used it to get to `my_image` in `option==2`.

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2
import SessionState

def Camera():
    frames1 = st.empty()
    button1 = st.button('DONE', key=0)
    while cap.isOpened():
        frames1.image(cap.read()[1], channels="BGR")
        if button1:
            my_image = cap.read()[1]
            cap.release()
            break
    return my_image


option = st.sidebar.radio('Choose the option', [0, 1])
session_state = SessionState.get(name='', img=None)
if option == 0:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    my_image = Camera()
    st.image(my_image, channels="BGR")
    session_state.img = my_image

if option == 1:
    my_image = session_state.img
    st.image(my_image, channels='BGR')
```

Comment: I believe SessionState only persists the value for the current user, so if you want to persist it across multiple users accessing your app, this might not work

Comment: For anyone wandering into this now, Streamlit has the session state built in with streamlit.session_state, no need for the gist.

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit runs top down each time there is an interaction event. In your code, `my_image = Camera()` is only run when `option==0`; when the radio button switches to the other option, `my_image` never gets defined.

Move the code that defines `cap` and `my_image` out of your first conditional statement.

Comment: Actually I am using different radio buttons for different pages. I want to capture the image and then to do some task on the image in a complete different environment.